Exception 28 : esp8266 cannot connect to arduino cloud
I am making a device that collects data like temperature, humidity, co levels and flame distance and transmits them through a LoRa Ra-02 AI Thinker to an esp8266 that next uploads them to the Arduino cloud to put them on a dashboard.
The problem is that even though the two devices connect and the data gets transmitted, when I add the ArduinoCloud.update(); command,the serial monitor prints the following:
epc1=0x40204c51 epc2=0x00000000 epc3=0x00000000 excvaddr=0x00000010 depc=0x00000000

>>>stack>>>

ctx: cont
sp: 3fff0540 end: 3fff0770 offset: 01a0
3fff06e0:  0000008b 00000000 3ffef260 402030f7  
3fff06f0:  00000081 00000081 3ffef260 402034b5  
3fff0700:  007a1200 00000001 3fff0778 40202944  
3fff0710:  00000081 00000080 3ffef694 40209694  
3fff0720:  19cf0e40 00000000 3ffef694 402097cf  
3fff0730:  19cf0e40 00000000 3ffef694 402099e2  
3fff0740:  3fffdad0 3ffef694 3ffef6f8 3fff07a8  
3fff0750:  3fffdad0 00000000 3fff0778 4020adb0  
3fff0760:  feefeffe feefeffe 3ffe8544 40100a09  
<<<stack<<<

When I don't use the ArduinoCloud.update(); command the code works fine through the monitor.
Here is the code I'm using:
#include <ArduinoIoTCloud.h>
#include <LoRa.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include "thingProperties.h"

#define SS 15
#define RST 16
#define DIO0 2

void setup() {
  // Initialize serial and wait for port to open:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  // This delay gives the chance to wait for a Serial Monitor without blocking if none is found
  delay(1500); 
while (!Serial);

  Serial.println("LoRa Receiver");

  LoRa.setPins(SS, RST, DIO0);

  if (!LoRa.begin(433E6)) {
    Serial.println("Starting LoRa failed!");
    while (1);
  // Defined in thingProperties.h
  initProperties();

  // Connect to Arduino IoT Cloud
  ArduinoCloud.begin(ArduinoIoTPreferredConnection);
  
  setDebugMessageLevel(2);
  ArduinoCloud.printDebugInfo();
}
}

void loop() {
  ArduinoCloud.update();
  
  // Check if there is any data available
  if (LoRa.parsePacket()) {
    // Read the received data
    String data = "";
    while (LoRa.available()) {
      data += (char)LoRa.read();
    }

    // Split the data by comma
    int index = data.indexOf(',');
    String str1 = data.substring(0, index);
    String str2 = data.substring(index + 1);

    // Convert the strings to float and integer
    temperature = str1.toFloat();
    co_levels = str1.toInt();
    humidity = str2.toFloat();
    flame_distance = str2.toInt();

    // Print the received data
    Serial.print("Received data: ");
    Serial.print("temperature:");
    Serial.print(temperature);
    Serial.println(", ");
    Serial.print("humidity:");
    Serial.print(humidity);
    Serial.println(", ");
    Serial.print("flame_distance:");
    Serial.print(flame_distance);
    Serial.println(", ");
    Serial.print("co_levels:");
    Serial.print(co_levels);
  }
}

